# How to access information in a URL request with Express?

Tags: json, express

How can I extract the location value of the following request with Express?

http://localhost:3000/campgrounds?location=Austin

Answer (score 0):

Use `req.query.*`.

```node
app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res) {
   res.status(200).send(req.query.location); 
});
```

Note: this won't work if your user doesn't input the `location` query.

Answer (score 0):

In the url `http://localhost:3000/campgrounds?location=Austin`

`location` is a query parameter and `Austin` is the value of the query parameter.

In express, get the value of the query parameter by invoking:

```js
req.query.location
```

see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query